# Python3 not installed, but installed

Tags: debian, python3, uninstall

I could not remove the python `3.9.1` from my debian, so I tried cleaning the python3 folders and files in `/usr` and `/bin` and `/share`.

But now when I try to install python3, it shows python3 already in latest version. When I run python3, it shows python3 not installed. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to force a re-installation:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall python3
```

Manually cleaning the Python 3-related folders and files didn’t update the package database, which is what determines which packages are considered as installed.

You’ll probably need to re-install other packages; use the following command to re-install all packages with missing files:

```
sudo debsums -s -ca 2>&1 | awk '/missing file/ { print $(NF-1) }' | xargs -r sudo apt install --reinstall
```